# How to place several servers (frontend + API) under one domain name using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing

This may be a bit too broad a question, but I am not sure how to phrase a Google search query for this.

I need to have the following structure:

1. mywebsite.com - frontend page running on one server (S3-hosted most likely)
2. mywebsite.com/ecommerce  - backend that communicates with frontend, setup as EC2 instance (Rails).
3. mywebsite.com/admin - some other logic that communicates with the above, also runs on EC2 instance.

Do I need some sort of a routing table? Is there anything on AWS that I can use for this without much setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Application Load Balancer would likely be suitable as they support [path based routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html) (more info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-achieve-path-based-routing-alb/))

Just a small warning: with limited knowledge of AWS you are likely to create but not recognize security issues. I suggest given this looks to be financial you should get an AWS consultant to review your infrastructure security, or better yet, to design infrastructure for you. Enterprises pay AWS consultants a lot of money to do this, but for a small website getting the basics set up (firewalls with security groups, security monitoring and alerting with guard duty, setting up backups with Data Lifecycle Manager and ideally setting up offsite backups) is not a huge amount of work.

Comment: thank you, I will look into this